# How can I put variables from http get method to http post method in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

can someone please help me with this problem? When i send an invalid form and a view returns, all ViewBag Collections are set to null.

AssurancesController

```
// GET: Assurances/Create
        public IActionResult Create(int HolderId, string FirstName, string LastName)
        {
            ViewBag.HolderId = HolderId;
            ViewBag.FirstName = FirstName;
            ViewBag.LastName = LastName;
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Assurances/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Type,Amount,Payment")] Assurance assurance)
        {
            string temp = Request.Form["hID"];
            assurance.PolicyholderId = int.Parse(temp);
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(assurance);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
            }
            return View(assurance);
        }
```

PolicyHolder Detail View

```
<h1>Details</h1>

<div>
    <h4>Policyholder</h4>
    <hr />
    <dl class="row">
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FirstName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LastName)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Email)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Email)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TelephoneNumber)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TelephoneNumber)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Street)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Street)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.City)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.City)
        </dd>
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.PostCode)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
            @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.PostCode)
        </dd>
    </dl>
</div>
<table class="mt-3 table-responsive-sm index-tabulka" border="1" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th width="38%">
                <div class="my-2 ml-1">
                    Pojištění
                </div>
            </th>
            <th witdh="38%">
                <div class="my-2 ml-1">
                    Částka
                </div>
            </th>
            <th width="24%"></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (Assurance assurance in ViewBag.Assurance)
        {
            <tr>
                <td width="38%">
                    <a class="my-2 ml-1" asp-controller="Assurances" asp-action="Details" asp-route-id=@assurance.Id>
                        @assurance.Type
                    </a>
                </td>
                <td witdh="38%">
                    <div class="my-2 ml-1">
                        @assurance.Amount
                    </div>
                </td>
                <td class="text-center" width="24%">
                    <a class="btn btn-danger tlacitka-tabulka my-2" asp-controller="Assurances" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@assurance.Id">Delete</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-warning tlacitka-tabulka text-white my-2" asp-controller="Assurances" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@assurance.Id">Edit</a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
<div class="text-center mt-3">
    <a class="btn btn-primary text-white" onclick=@Html.ActionLink("Create Assurance", "Create", "Assurances", new { HolderId = Model.Id, FirstName = Model.FirstName, LastName = Model.LastName}, null)</a>
    <a class="btn btn-warning text-white" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@Model?.Id">Edit</a>
    <a class="btn btn-danger" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="@Model?.Id">Delete</a>
</div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
```

Assurance Create View

```
<h2 class="mt-3">Přidat pojištění k @ViewBag.FirstName @ViewBag.LastName</h2>
<div class="row mt-3">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            @* EDITED *@
            ID pojištěnce: @ViewBag.HolderId
            @Html.Hidden("hID", (object)ViewBag.HolderId)


            @*<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="FirstName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="FirstName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="FirstName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="LastName" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="LastName" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="LastName" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>*@
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Type" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Type" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Type" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Amount" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Amount" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Amount" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Payment" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Payment" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Payment" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group text-center">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-primary" />

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

I expect that the ViewBag Collections have got the same values in the http post method as in the http get method.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not setting `ViewBag` value in `POST` method.

Modify it like this

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Type,Amount,Payment")] Assurance assurance)
{
    var temp = Request.Form["hID"];
    assurance.PolicyholderId = int.Parse(temp);

    ViewBag.HolderId = assurance.PolicyholderId;

    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        _context.Add(assurance);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
    }

    return View(assurance);
}
```